# span contenteditable width won't work

Tags: css, contenteditable, html

When the span tag is used with the attribute contenteditable="true" then it ignores all width css

```
    <span contenteditable="true" style="width:400px;border:1px solid black;">
    Content filler
    </span>
```

The above produces this
   
[image]
Does anybody know how to make it so the box doesn't conform to the text like this and follows regular CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

span is a `display:inline` element. Width doesn't work on inline elements.

Apply either `display:inline-block;` or `display:block;` to the span.